# SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression, where is the missing expression?

Tags: sql, oracle

Qns: Item Description and the treatment date of all treatments for any patients named Jessie Stange (ie GivenName is Jessie & FamilyName is Stange)

What I wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Description, 
  Date as treatmentDate 
WHERE doothey.Patient P, 
      doothey.Account A, 
      doothey.AccountLine AL, 
      doothey.Item.I AND 
      P.PatientID = A.PatientID AND 
      A.AccountNo = AL.AccountNo AND 
      AL.ItemNo = I.ItemNo AND 
     (p.FamilyName = 'Stange' AND p.GivenName = 'Jessie');
```

Error:

> Error at Command Line:1 Column:30 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" *Cause: *Action:

What is the missing expression?

Comment: Where is From cluase in select query

Comment: You are missing `FROM` clause

Comment: where is your `FROM` clause?

Comment: I don't like the look of `AND P.PatientID = A.PatientID AND A.AccountNo = AL.AccountNo AND AL.ItemNo = I.ItemNo`, looks like `INNER JOIN`s should be specified.

Comment: I try to avoid INNER Joins as I am bad with them. However I will practice more.

Comment: @user2901548 what do you mean bad with them? if you are speaking syntax wise then, yes you should practice a lot more. These are sort of the basics of SQL without which you will have poorly constructed queries which could result in major problems for any application these queries are supporting.

Answer (score 4):

Correct syntax below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description, Date as treatmentDate 
FROM
 doothey.Patient P, doothey.Account A, doothey.AccountLine AL, doothey.Item I 
WHERE P.PatientID = A.PatientID AND A.AccountNo = AL.AccountNo 
AND AL.ItemNo = I.ItemNo    
AND (p.FamilyName = 'Stange' AND p.GivenName = 'Jessie');
```

Although above query would work but the recommended way is by using ANSI SQL JOIN syntax is

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description, Date as treatmentDate 
FROM doothey.Patient P
INNER JOIN doothey.Account A
    ON P.PatientID = A.PatientID 
INNER JOIN doothey.AccountLine AL
    ON A.AccountNo = AL.AccountNo
INNER JOIN doothey.Item I 
    ON AL.ItemNo = I.ItemNo 
WHERE   
 p.FamilyName = 'Stange' AND p.GivenName = 'Jessie';
```

Comment: Error at Command Line:1 Column:21
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action: (This is strange)

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented you missed the `FROM` statement in your select.

I would also suggest **not** just declaring all your tables in the `FROM` and specifying links in the `WHERE` clause, but instead `join` the tables together using `LEFT JOIN` and/or `INNER JOIN`s, etc.

Below is the query I think should cover what I have tried to explain above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Description, 
    Date as treatmentDate 
FROM
    doothey.Patient P
INNER JOIN
    doothey.Account A
ON
    P.PatientID = A.PatientID    
INNER JOIN
    doothey.AccountLine AL
ON
    A.AccountNo = AL.AccountNo
INNER JOIN
    doothey.Item.I  
ON
    AL.ItemNo = I.ItemNo
WHERE 
    p.FamilyName = 'Stange' 
AND 
    p.GivenName = 'Jessie'
```